# how to acces value in 2 d array with pointer declaration

Tags: c, pointers

question1 : 
how to acces the value 2 in the array 
(i don't want to use declaration like : int t[][])

```
int *t[3] ={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

question2 :

```
int * t1 = {1,2,3}; // how this line of code compiles
```

Comment: For the second question, enable warnings (if the compiler doesn't already give you warnings for that).

Comment: And for question one, *why* don't you want to use e.g. `int t[3][2]`?

Comment: `*(t + (rowNumber*COL) + colNumber) = val` will work for question 1, but you really should just use `t[3][2]`

Comment: once you understand that a multi dim array is kept in the memory as a continuous block same as a one dim array- you can understand that if you must, you can just go through it with a pointer the same way and just do the calculations yourself.

Comment: @Rietty what is COL if it's not colNumber , Thank you

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's for learning purposes , i don't ave problems with that declaration ,  i used this `int *ptr= t; ptr++;` ==> **ptr at  @24 and *ptr gives the value 2** now i want to acces it with the declaration above , Thank you

Comment: @SaifFaidi Total number of columns you have.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the question:

```
int * t1 = {1,2,3}; // how this line of code compiles
```

the following is the results of trying to compile:

```
int main( void )
{
    int * t1 = {1,2,3};
}
```

which I put into a file named 'untitled2.c'

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" 
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:7:14: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
int * t1 = {1,2,3};
            ^
untitled2.c:7:14: note: (near initialization for ‘t1’)
untitled2.c:7:16: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
int * t1 = {1,2,3};
              ^
untitled2.c:7:16: note: (near initialization for ‘t1’)
untitled2.c:7:18: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
int * t1 = {1,2,3};
                ^
untitled2.c:7:18: note: (near initialization for ‘t1’)
untitled2.c:7:8: warning: unused variable ‘t1’ [-Wunused-variable]
int * t1 = {1,2,3};
      ^~
```

So, how does this compile?  It doesn't

Comment: If you remove all your flags, and just compile with `gcc test.c`  it give a bunch of warning, but I did get a `a.out`.

Comment: Just because the compiler outputs a executable file does NOT mean that the contents of the file are correct.   Correct the warnings, cause you cannot depend on an output file being correct when the compiler outputs a bunch of warnings

Comment: I agree. But you said it did not compile, that why i said that. The compiled program is probably garbage.

Comment: I want to understand how the values are stored in memory ,  let's say a random address is associated to the array t , wich is an array of pointers to integers ,doing this test                                                                                            
  `printf("t at %p \ and value =%d \n",t,t[0]); `==> **t at 0c and value = 1**
  `printf("t+1 at %p \ and value =%d \n",t+1,t[1]);` ==> **t+1 at 10 and value = 3**

Comment: ** logic interpretation :  this declaration `int *t[3] ={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}; ` creates an array of integers and initializes its pointers with the first value of each 1d array , means `t[0] = 1 or 0x01 , t[1] = 0x03 , t[2] = 0x05 ` in other terms  we cannot acces the value 2 because this initilaisation dosen't considers `{1,2}` as an array of values  pointed by t [0]